# How to discover existing partition names in ssas tabular model-2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, ssas-tabular, xmla

How to find existing partition names in cube.

I would like to check dynamically whether a partition exist or not using loop in SQL Linked server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the compatibility level that you're working with is, but for level 1200 or above the `TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS` DMV can be queried from an `OPENQUERY` linked server connection for tabular models.  The `Name` column will need to be escaped using double brackets as done below.  If the model is below compatibility level 1200, I'd recommend using the other answer provided by @vercelli for the `DISCOVER_STORAGE_TABLE_COLUMN_SEGMENTS` DMV which can also be queried from a linked server.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
'SELECT 
    [Name] 
FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this MDX query:

```
select distinct
    PARTITION_NAME
from
    $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_STORAGE_TABLE_COLUMN_SEGMENTS
```

Founded [here](http://www.bonk.dk/dynamic-partitioning-tabular-cube/)